# How to inject services into a custom IHttpHandler in Orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, autofac, ihttphandler

I am developing a module for Orchard which will restrict the items in the Media folder by looking up the authenticated user permissions.

The first thing was editing the web.config in the Media folder like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="MediaFileAccess.AuthorizedMediaHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
      <add name="AuthorizedFile" path="*" verb="*"
           type="MediaFileAccess.AuthorizedMediaHandler,MediaFileAccess"
           preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The handler which is registered in the web.config:

```cs
public class AuthorizedMediaHandler : IHttpHandler, IDependency
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

    public AuthorizedMediaHandler(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Do something using the injected services...
    }
}
```

When I navigate to a Media item url system throws MissingMethodException. That's normal because system cannot find the parameterless constructor.

So, how can I inject the Orchard services into a IHttpHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you won't be able to inject dependencies like this you can still access Orchard'd DI container with the magic of `IShim`. Check out how e.g. `OrchardLog4netLogger` resolves dependencies from `IOrchardHostContainer`.

Keep in mind though that this container is the application-wide one: to be able to resolve your standard `IDependency` types you'll need to first get the `ShellContext` from `IOrchardHost`, then create a `WorkContextScope` from its `LifetimeScope` as `LifetimeScope.CreateWorkContextScope()`.

I know it seems complicated, and indeed there are a lot of hoops involved. But the bottom line is that this way you can resolve services from Orchard's (and its shells') DI containers in any class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Glympse out? uses HttpHandlers, theres a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179655/how-to-use-glimpse-in-orchard-cms).

there is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179655/how-to-use-glimpse-in-orchard-cms) that got me thinking.

Get your web.configs working and it should be ok. i do not know about the `IDependency` bit, might not need it.

Comment: I couldn't find a Orchard spesific code in Glympse, it doesn't consume Orchard services as I see :(

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely not able to inject. sorry,i omitted that in my answer earlier.

You can create a Orchard module that adds a filter or  with a Controller that hijacks the route you specify and serves the file from somewhere actually safe.

Orchard takes over IIS. that is why you need to add the staticfilemodule in the folder's web.config, to let IIS in and that is what makes it not secure.

If you really need to go that road, perhaps a very quick service call to Orchard or talking directly to a db.

Comment: I created a Controller and set a route with "Media/{*path}" pattern, then set RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles to true in Global.asax.cs file, finally it works :)